# $S_4$ is not supersolvable? Why am I wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I read that $S_4$ is an example of a solvable group who is not a supersolvable group.

In order to prove it is solvable, we see that:

$\{e\}<\{(1),(12)(34)\}<K<A_4<S_4$

where $K$ is the Klein group. All of its factor groups are $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z_3}$, this is, cyclic groups of prime order. So, as $S_4$ is finite, this means that $S_4$ is solvable.

The definition of a supersolvable groups says that the group must have a normal series in which its factor groups are cyclic. Well, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z_3}$ are cyclic.

Then why $S_4$ is not supersolvable?

Comment: The definition seems to me to require that every group in the series be normal in $S_4$, which is not true of $\{(1), (12)(34)\}$.

Comment: @RolfHoyer, that does not prove $S_4$ is not supersolvable, but only that this particular series of subgroups does not fit the condition for showing $S_4$ is supersolvable. Maybe another series of subgroups would fit the definition. A reason $S_4$ is not supersolvable is that its only normal subgroups are $\{(1)\}$, $K$, $A_4$, and $S_4$. In particular, since none of these groups (besides $\{(1)\}$) are cyclic, there is no normal series for $S_4$ whose successive quotient groups are all cyclic.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition, a group $G$ is supersolvable when we have $G=G_1>G_2>\ldots>G_n=\{e\}$, where each $G_i$ is normal *in $G$* and $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is cyclic for each $i<n$.

This implies in particular that (unless $G$ is trivial) $G_{n-1}/G_n\cong G_{n-1}$ is a nontrivial cyclic, normal subgroup of $G$. But $S_4$ has no such subgroups (unlike $S_3$, which has a normal subgroup of order $3$).

Comment: Oh, so we need each $G_i$ is normal in $G$. I see my mistake now. Thank you.

Comment: @Sandor: Note that for finite groups, if you only require $G_i$ to be normal in $G_{i-1}$, then it doesn't matter whether you require $G_i/G_{i+1}$ to be just abelian or cyclic, the latter case merely makes the sequence potentially longer. It follows from the fact that a finite abelian group always has a cyclic quotient (which is a consequence of the fundamental theorem on finitely generated abelian groups).